# The operation cannot be completed: - Create/update: a mandatory field is not set. - Delete: another model requires the record being deleted...Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I want to create orders from backend pos. So, I made button CREATE in pos.order visible.
But when clicking on button , I got this error :

```
The operation cannot be completed:
- Create/update: a mandatory field is not set.
- Delete: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.

Model: Point of Sale Orders (pos.order), Field: Returned (amount_return)
```

Here is my code:
//.xml

```
<record id="view_pos_order_create_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view_pos_order_create_extend</field>
        <field name="model">pos.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_order_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
                 <attribute name="create">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

//.py

```
 class PosOrderExtend(models.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.order"
    _description = "Point of Sale Orders"
    _order = "id desc"

      @api.onchange('payment_ids', 'lines', 'partner_id')
        def _onchange_amount_all(self):
            for order in self:
                currency = self.env.company.currency_id
                if self.partner_id.property_product_pricelist.currency_id:
                    currency = self.partner_id.property_product_pricelist.currency_id
                order.amount_paid = sum(payment.amount for payment in order.payment_ids)
                order.amount_return = sum(payment.amount < 0 and payment.amount or 0 for payment in order.payment_ids)
                order.amount_tax = currency.round(
                    sum(self._amount_line_tax(line, order.fiscal_position_id) for line in order.lines))
                amount_untaxed = currency.round(sum(line.price_subtotal for line in order.lines))
                order.amount_total = order.amount_tax + amount_untaxed
```

What's wrong please? How can I fix it ?
Thanks.

Comment: The error message clearly shows that the issue is with your res.currency object. So either:
1. There's no currency set for your order pricelist try to check pricelist in your POS config. Or,
2. Multiple currencies found against the pricelist, this could be possible if you are using any third party pricelist customization.

Comment: @Hammad Qureshi  , in pos configuration , the 'Pricelists' and 'Multi-Currencies' in pricing menu are not checked. So, I have to fix it by code , or should be a configuration?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You write about a create button, but the traceback is showing a `onchange` triggering event. Can you share your code please?

Comment: @CZoellner, I only added an xml file to set button visible. The error is in function standard odoo '_onchange_amount_all' , when printing currency was empty. So I changed it to company currency , but when saving I got another error of :

The operation cannot be completed:
- Create/update: a mandatory field is not set.
- Delete: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.

Model: Point of Sale Orders (pos.order), Field: Returned (amount_return), any idea about how to solve it please?

Comment: I edited the post .

Comment: please any help about fixing the error ?

Comment: any solution yet !? i've got the same problem ,even thought i'm adding product_id to the line i'm creating it still tlling me that it's empty